# How to understand this code snippet in the bcopy.c of bionic?

Tags: android, c, bionic

I read the memcpy implementation in the http://androidxref.com/4.0.4/xref/bionic/libc/string/bcopy.c
find following code is hard to understand, can anybody explain it?

```
 36 /*
 37  * sizeof(word) MUST BE A POWER OF TWO
 38  * SO THAT wmask BELOW IS ALL ONES
 39  */
 40 typedef long word;      /* "word" used for optimal copy speed */
 41 
 42 #define wsize   sizeof(word)
 43 #define wmask   (wsize - 1)
 44
```

...

```
        /*
 78          * Copy forward.
 79          */
 80         t = (long)src;  /* only need low bits */
 81         if ((t | (long)dst) & wmask) {
 82             /*
 83              * Try to align operands.  This cannot be done
 84              * unless the low bits match.
 85              */
 86             if ((t ^ (long)dst) & wmask || length < wsize)
 87                 t = length;
 88             else
 89                 t = wsize - (t & wmask);
```

What is mean of these bitwise operations? What is their intent?

Comment: I know these bitwise operators, and I want to know these logic meaning.

Comment: Heh, I recognize my old code there... :-)  This is basically just the way one writes this in assembly languages (most of them anyway), converted to C code.  Of course when you're doing raw assembly you can make use of any special machine instructions and characteristics.

Comment: Chris Torek? Whoa, Victor hit the jackpot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The basic idea is to meet alignment constraints: each "word" to be copied one word at a time must be aligned on a "word" boundary.

Some CPUs have this as a fundamental constraint, that loads and stores must occur on a "natural" boundary.  On older ARM processors the low bits of the address are actually ignored entirely, so that a load or store of two bytes from an odd-valued address have the same effect as:

```
short w = *(short *)(addr & ~1);
```

for instance.  On some other CPUs an unaligned load or store results in a trap (MIPS and SPARC for instance), and still others will just do it, but with a performance penalty (x86).

So, suppose you're copying a large number of bytes (say, 4096 of them) from address 0x12345 to address 0x22345, and that the "word size" is 4 bytes.  If we first copy three bytes, the addresses will now be 0x12348 and 0x22348.  At this point we can copy just 1023 4-byte words, one word at a time, without tripping over any alignment issues.  After that we'll have one remaining byte to copy, because 4096 = 3 + (4 * 1023) + 1.

This all makes the assumption that bytes are all addressed individually, even when loading and storing "words".  This assumption is false on some machines: for instance, the old Data General MV10000 CPU would address "words" using "word addresses", which are essentially byte addresses divided by two.  (It's thus impossible to address a "word" that spans two bytes: the word at location 0 has byte addresses 0 and 1 but word address 0; the word at location 1 has byte addresses 2 and 3; the word at location 2 has byte addresses 4 and 5; and so on.)  On machines like this, you may need to use a different version of bcopy.c.

As @Alex noted, the XOR is just making sure that it is actually possible to align the two addresses.  If you're copying from 0x12345 to 0x22345, it is; but if you're copying from 0x12345 to 0x22344, the two addresses will never line up.

Comment: If `short w = *(short *)(addr & ~1);` is not aligned, then that's undefined behavior in C/C++. If the code is not removed by the compiler, then you get either (1) a `sig_bus` on older ARM processors in some cases, or (2) a performance penalty when the CPU fixes up the misaligned access in some cases.

Comment: @jww: yes, I tried to cover all these actual outcomes: "On older ARM ... the low bits ... are ignored ... on other CPUs ... a trap ... still others ... a performance penalty".  The example CPUs in that sentence are meant as examples only, not complete lists.

Comment: Original ARM behaviour is to rotate single unaligned loads, but ignore the low bits on multiple loads ans stores.

Comment: @TimothyBaldwin: Interesting. How does the rotation work - is it left rotate or right rotate? Does it use the register width (32 bits), or the load width (are there 16 bit loads?)? Is it byte-wise rotation? (This seems much more useful than bit-wise since the offset can only go to 3 at most.) DEC Alpha originally had only full-word load, as I understand it. but I can't remember if it trapped or ignored low bits.

Answer (score 6):

Just do it step by step:

```
t = (long)src;
if ((t | (long)dst) & wmask)
```

These check if at least one of `src` and `dst` isn't a multiple of `sizeof(long)`.

```
if ((t ^ (long)dst) & wmask || length < wsize)
```

This checks if `src` and `dst` are aligned differently w.r.t. `sizeof(long)` (IOW, aren't "equal" multiples of `sizeof(long)`) or if `length < sizeof(long)-1`.

At the end you receive in `t` how many bytes have to be copied as bytes between unaligned locations, either all (`length`), or just enough (less than `sizeof(long)`) to reach addresses that are multiple of `sizeof(long)` from where the rest can be copied in units of `long`. And the latter is the speed optimization.

To see all that you have to know that an integer, when expressed in binary, is a multiple of a certain power of 2 when its least significant bits below that power of 2 are all zeroes.

Examples:

100<sub>2</sub> (4<sub>10</sub>) is a multiple of 100<sub>2</sub> (4<sub>10</sub>)
1100<sub>2</sub> (12<sub>10</sub>) is a multiple of 100<sub>2</sub> (4<sub>10</sub>)
10000<sub>2</sub> (16<sub>10</sub>) is a multiple of 100<sub>2</sub> (4<sub>10</sub>)
0<sub>2</sub> (0<sub>10</sub>) is a multiple of 100<sub>2</sub> (4<sub>10</sub>)
11<sub>2</sub> (3<sub>10</sub>) is not a multiple of 100<sub>2</sub> (4<sub>10</sub>)
1101<sub>2</sub> (13<sub>10</sub>) is not a multiple of 100<sub>2</sub> (4<sub>10</sub>)

This is what `& (sizeof(long)-1)` is used for.

You also need to know that a value `XORed` with itself gives 0 and when you `XOR` different values the result is non-zero. So you can use `XOR` for comparison. And that's what `(t ^ (long)dst)` is for.