# Android NDK for x86_64 has no reference for bcopy and index

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am trying to compile Lame sound library with Android NDK for x86_64 architecture. I am getting the below link error for undefined references to `bcopy` and `index`:

```
jni/libmp3lame/encoder.c:471: error: undefined reference to 'bcopy'
jni/libmp3lame/encoder.c:476: error: undefined reference to 'bcopy'
jni/libmp3lame/id3tag.c:1125: error: undefined reference to 'index'
jni/libmp3lame/newmdct.c:1036: error: undefined reference to 'bcopy'
jni/libmp3lame/util.c:685: error: undefined reference to 'bcopy'
```

The code successfully compiles for x86 and arm architectures.

So I digged through NDK's libs a bit and noticed that `bcopy` and `index` are both exported in `libc.so` for x86 and arm platforms but not for x86_64 (see below `objdump` outputs).

```
$> objdump -d android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android-21/arch-arm/usr/lib/libc.so | grep bcopy -A 6
0000b000 <bcopy>:
    b000:   e52db004 push   {fp}    ; (str fp, [sp, #-4]!)
    b004:   e28db000 add    fp, sp, #0
    b008:   e28bd000 add    sp, fp, #0
    b00c:   e8bd0800 ldmfd  sp!, {fp}
    b010:   e12fff1e bx lr


$> objdump -d android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android-21/arch-x86/usr/lib/libc.so | grep -A 6 bcopy
00009fb0 <bcopy>:
    9fb0:   55                   push   %ebp
    9fb1:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
    9fb3:   5d                   pop    %ebp
    9fb4:   c3                   ret


$>  objdump -d android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android-21/arch-x86_64/usr/lib/libc.so | grep -A 6 bcopy
<<NOTHING FOUND>>
```

Any thoughts? Below are my Android.mk and Application.mk files.

Application.mk:

```
APP_ABI:=x86_64
APP_PLATFORM := android-21
```

Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

APP_PLATFORM := android-21

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE        := libmp3lame

LOCAL_SRC_FILES     := \
...<list-of-.c-files>...

LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: Android x86_64 is interesting. I did not know Android offered it until your question (which caused to to find [Developers, start your 64-bit engines](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/XG1WmNDMe8H) from the Android NDK team).

Comment: I could not even get Autoconf to configure for the target Android x86_64. How did you manage to build it? This is a related question on Stack Overflow: [Autoconf triplet for Android x86_64?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27894831/608639). Also see the question on the Autoconf mailing list: [How To Configure for Android? (Redux for x86_64)](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/autoconf/2015-01/index.html).

Comment: I didn't do any configuration of any sorts, other than installing android-21 using the package manager. BTW, the only reason that I _seem_ to need to get a native compilation in x86_64 is to have it run in my emulator. I am using a 64-bit mac and a x86[-32] is insanely slow. In fact I couldn't even get the emulator to boot up. Is there any other way to get the emulator run with x86 arch? P.S. I am very very new to Android - exactly 2 weeks now :)

Comment: Click *Edit* to edit your question. Add your `Application.mk` and `Android.mk`.

Answer (score 13):

You can fix this cleanly with a single line in `Application.mk` ([docs](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/application_mk.html)):

```
APP_CFLAGS += -DSTDC_HEADERS
```

#### Why?

`LAME` assumes that certain symbols will be accessible without explicit inclusion via `#include`. However, it also provides a way to signal that explicit inclusion is necessary.

In my distribution, the conflictive files (`machine.h` and `id3tag.c`) have something like this:

```
#ifdef STDC_HEADERS
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <string.h>
#endif
```

This is the block you need to trigger, by setting the `STDC_HEADERS` preprocessor variable. The line above, with the `-D` flag, tells the C compiler to create it.

Comment: Superthanks for quick and easy solution! Also with the same effect I used LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DSTDC_HEADERS in Android.mk

Comment: Thank you for saving my weekend!!

Answer (score 3):

To fix `bcopy` issue, I added `#include <strings.h>` in `machine.h` and `id3tag.h`.

To fix `index` issue, I ended up commenting out the `#define strchar index` line in both `machine.h` and `id3tag.c`:

```
#ifdef STDC_HEADERS
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <string.h>
#else
# ifndef HAVE_STRCHR
//#  define strchr index
#  define strrchr rindex
# endif
char   *strchr(), *strrchr();
# ifndef HAVE_MEMCPY
#  define memcpy(d, s, n) bcopy ((s), (d), (n))
#  define memmove(d, s, n) bcopy ((s), (d), (n))
# endif
#endif
```

Comment: What you probably really wanted is to add `-DSTDC_HEADERS` to your cflags.

Answer (score 0):

I have it in `strings.h`, but its a `#define`:

```
$ cd /opt/android-ndk-r10d
$ grep -R bcopy * | grep x86_64
platforms/android-21/arch-x86_64/usr/include/linux/mroute6.h:#define IF_COPY(f, t) bcopy(f, t, sizeof(*(f)))
platforms/android-21/arch-x86_64/usr/include/strings.h:#define bcopy(b1, b2, len) \
platforms/android-21/arch-x86_64/usr/include/strings.h:#define bcopy(b1, b2, len) (void)(__builtin_memmove((b2), (b1), (len)))
```

Here's what it looks like (taken from the header `strings.h`):

```
#if defined(__BIONIC_FORTIFY)
#  define bcopy(b1, b2, len) \
    (void)(__builtin___memmove_chk((b2), (b1), (len), __bos0(b2)))
#  define bzero(b, len) \
    (void)(__builtin___memset_chk((b), '\0', (len), __bos0(b)))
#else
# define bcopy(b1, b2, len) (void)(__builtin_memmove((b2), (b1), (len)))
# define bzero(b, len) (void)(__builtin_memset((b), '\0', (len)))
#endif
```

Earlier version of the Android runtime provided it as a library call. See, for example, [How to understand this code snippet in the bcopy.c of bionic?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11237654/608639).

It sounds like its another case of the headers changing at `android-21`. That is, its a function that used to present as an export in a library, but now available in a headers. See, for example, [Cannot load library: reloc_library[1285]: cannot locate 'rand'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27338318/608639).

I think the workaround is to re-compile the Lame sound library with `android-21`, and not an earlier version of the toolchain.

Also, there are various `config.h` that have the following comment:

```
/* HAS_BCOPY:
 *  This symbol is defined if the bcopy() routine is available to
 *  copy blocks of memory.
 */
#define HAS_BCOPY   /**/
```

You can find the `config.h` at, for example, `android-ndk-r10d/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/lib/perl5/5.16.2/darwin-2level/CORE/config.h`.

If its not something obvious (like you already are compiling under `android-21` and `arch` is correct), then we'll need to see how your project is setup (like what does `Application.mk` look like, or what `--sysroot` is being used).

Comment: I added `APP_PLATFORM := android-21` in my `Application.mk` (the only other line in the file is `APP_ABI:=x86_64` to pick the architecture. But the result is the same.Does setting `APP_PLATFORM` have the same effect as adding SYSROOT? Otherwise, how can I set SYSROOT - is it a commandline option of some sort?

Comment: Since jww found that it indeed is available in the headers, can you check whether `encoder.c` (and the other files mentioned) actually do include `strings.h` (which should redirect it to `__builtin_memmove`)? (If it isn't included, you'd get build warnings like "incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'bcopy'").

Comment: @mstorsjo - I was able to build from the command line using a cross-compile script. The project had some issues, but they were related to Autoconf and `libtool`. Once I got through the Autoconf issues, I got a `libmp3lame.so` out of it.

Comment: @mstorsjo - You might be onto something. `$CC $CFLAGS -I./include -M libmp3lame/encoder.c | grep strings.h` (when set for the Android x86_64 cross-compile environment) did not produce any hits. Maybe he should include `<strings.h>` in `lame.h` and guard it on `__ANDROID__`. Placing it in `lame.h` with the `__ANDROID__` guard does produce `grep` hits.

Comment: Possibly. Do note that lame's configure script checks for the `strings.h` header (and sets `HAVE_STRINGS_H` in `config.h` accordingly), but nothing in the actual library seems to include `strings.h` and nothing uses `HAVE_STRINGS_H` for anything either (at least not in the version of the source that I'm checking here). So something like `#ifdef HAVE_STRINGS_H #include <strings.h> #endif` in the right place would probably be even better. (I'm not sure if `lame.h` is the right place for that, though, since the public header shouldn't use `config.h`.)

Comment: I included `<strings.h>` which solved the missing references for `bcopy`. But the same issue for `index` still stands.