# Autoconf triplet for Android x86_64?

Tags: android, configuration, android-ndk, cross-compiling, autoconf

I wanted to examine the issue from this question: [Android NDK for x86_64 has no reference for bcopy and index](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27893149/608639). In the question, the poster asked about Android x86_64 and `bcopy` in relation to the [Lame sound library](http://lame.sourceforge.net/).

I set up my cross-compile environment, set the paths for tools and sysroot, and exported the usual suspects like `CC`, `CXX` `CFLAGS`, `CXXFLAGS`, etc. For example:

```
$ echo $CC
x86_64-linux-android-gcc
$ which x86_64-linux-android-gcc
/opt/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/x86_64-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/x86_64-linux-android-gcc
```

And:

```
$ export CFLAGS="--sysroot=$ANDROID_SYSROOT"
$ echo $CFLAGS
--sysroot=/opt/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android-21/arch-x86_64
```

The above is usually enough to get things started. Everything is set correctly, and I can use the script to build other libraries, like Crypto++ and OpenSSL (with some minor adjustments).

However, I have not been able to configure for Android x86_64 (see below). I can't seem to find the right triplet.

What triplet does Android x86_64 use with Autoconf?

---

Under Autoconf, AC's "build" is what most people consider "host", and AC's "host" is what most people consider "target". So the options are actually correct when cross compiling.

```
$ ./configure --build=`./config.guess` --host=x86_64-linux-androideabi
checking build system type... i686-apple-darwin12.5.0
checking host system type... Invalid configuration
`x86_64-linux-androideabi': system `androideabi' not recognized
configure: error: /bin/sh ./config.sub x86_64-linux-androideabi failed

$ ./configure --build=`./config.guess` --host=x86_64-linux-android
checking build system type... i686-apple-darwin12.5.0
checking host system type... Invalid configuration
`x86_64-linux-android': system `android' not recognized
configure: error: /bin/sh ./config.sub x86_64-linux-android failed

$ ./configure --build=`./config.guess`
checking build system type... i686-apple-darwin12.5.0
checking host system type... i686-apple-darwin12.5.0
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... ./install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking for gcc... x86_64-linux-android-gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... configure: error: in
`/Users/android/lame-3.99.5':
configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'.
See `config.log' for more details
```

Answer (score 0):

I fetched [autoconf-2.69.tar.xz](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/autoconf) from the GNU FTP site. I found the latest `config.guess` and `config.sub` in the `build-aux` directory and used it for the LAME MP3 encoder project.

It appears the triplet is `x86_64-linux-android`.

The project has a broken link though. The invocation of the compiler driver through libtool that creates the shared object lacks `CFLAGS`, so `--sysroot` is not passed to the linker. That causes a bunch of link errors due to missing system libraries, like `crtbegin_so.o`, `crtend_so.o`, `-lc` and `-ldl`.

The fix for that is to manually run the the failed command from the `libmp3lame` directory. Prepend the command with `$CC $CFLAGS <rest of project's command>`.