# A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000004 (code=1), thread 22791

Tags: java, android, c++, multithreading, android-ndk

I created an existing lame encoder by going through the documentation from samsung [Porting and using LAME MP3 on Android with JNI](http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do;jsessionid=cvYLJYpWG2pttCvJsVtnTGX4vJYDndxz6Q7664P2tSXDSKMbZQnD!-1904197406?v=T000000090)

then I had some problem with native library I solved it with another question from stackoverflow [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27893149/android-ndk-for-x86-64-has-no-reference-for-bcopy-and-index)

now i got the .so files but when i run it throws the following error A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000004 (code=1), thread 22791
**A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000004 (code=1), thread 22791**

i think it is due to some synchronization problem...
this is my MainActivity.

```
  package com.lameencoder;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  static {
    System.loadLibrary("mp3lame");
}

private native void initEncoder(int numChannels, int sampleRate, int bitRate, int mode, int quality);

private native void destroyEncoder();

private native int encodeFile(String sourcePath, String targetPath);

public static final int NUM_CHANNELS = 1;
public static final int SAMPLE_RATE = 16000;
public static final int BITRATE = 128;
public static final int MODE = 1;
public static final int QUALITY = 2;
private AudioRecord mRecorder;
private short[] mBuffer;
private final String startRecordingLabel = "Start recording";
private final String stopRecordingLabel = "Stop recording";
private boolean mIsRecording = false;
private File mRawFile;
private File mEncodedFile;
private Button startRecording,stopRecording;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initRecorder();
    initEncoder(NUM_CHANNELS, SAMPLE_RATE, BITRATE, MODE, QUALITY);

    startRecording = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    startRecording.setText(startRecordingLabel);

    startRecording.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {
            if (!mIsRecording) {
                mIsRecording = true;
                try{

                    mRecorder.startRecording();
                    mRawFile = getFile("raw");
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                startBufferedWrite(mRawFile);
            }
        }
    });

    stopRecording =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    stopRecording.setText(stopRecordingLabel);

    stopRecording.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(mIsRecording){
                mIsRecording = false;
                try {
                    mRecorder.stop();
                    mEncodedFile = getFile("mp3");
                    int result = encodeFile(mRawFile.getAbsolutePath(), mEncodedFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    if (result == 0) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Encoded to " + mEncodedFile.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    try{
        mRecorder.release();
    }catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"recorder resources are not released",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    destroyEncoder();
    super.onDestroy();
}

private void initRecorder() {
    int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLE_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
    mBuffer = new short[bufferSize];
    mRecorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, SAMPLE_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferSize);
}

private void startBufferedWrite(final File file) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            DataOutputStream output = null;
            try {
                output = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file)));
                while (mIsRecording) {
                    int readSize = mRecorder.read(mBuffer, 0, mBuffer.length);
                    for (int i = 0; i < readSize; i++) {
                        output.writeShort(mBuffer[i]);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (output != null) {
                    try {
                        output.flush();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } finally {
                        try {
                            output.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

private File getFile(final String suffix) {
    File filePath;
    Time time = new Time();
    time.setToNow();
    /*try{
        filePath= new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), time.format("%Y%m%d%H%M%S") + "." + suffix);
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }*/
    filePath= new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), time.format("%Y%m%d%H%M%S") + "." + suffix);
    return filePath;
}
```

`

the application runs in the phone but it looks like it records when **startRecording** is pressed when I clicked **stopRecording** the logcat says encoding started and gives the error message

**A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000004 (code=1), thread 22791**

and I saw many questions of this type but none seem to be an answer..

this is my logcat correspondance..

```
    `03-08 22:57:10.226  25288-25288/com.lameencoder D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-     enabling CheckJNI
     03-08 22:57:10.416  25288-25288/com.lameencoder D/dalvikvm﹕ Trying to  load lib /data/app-lib/com.lameencoder-1/libmp3lame.so 0x41662a18
     03-08 22:57:10.416  25288-25288/com.lameencoder D/dalvikvm﹕ Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.lameencoder-1/libmp3lame.so 0x41662a18
     03-08 22:57:10.416  25288-25288/com.lameencoder D/dalvikvm﹕ No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/com.lameencoder-1/libmp3lame.so 0x41662a18, skipping init
     03-08 22:57:10.496  25288-25288/com.lameencoder D/LAME ENCODER﹕ Init parameters:
     03-08 22:57:10.496  25288-25288/com.lameencoder D/LAME ENCODER﹕ Number of channels: 1
     03-08 22:57:10.496  25288-25288/com.lameencoder D/LAME ENCODER﹕ Sample rate: 16000
     03-08 22:57:10.496  25288-25288/com.lameencoder D/LAME ENCODER﹕ Bitrate: 128
     03-08 22:57:10.496  25288-25288/com.lameencoder D/LAME ENCODER﹕ Mode: 1
     03-08 22:57:10.496  25288-25288/com.lameencoder D/LAME ENCODER﹕ Quality: 2
     03-08 22:57:10.516  25288-25288/com.lameencoder D/LAME ENCODER﹕ Init returned: 0
     03-08 22:57:10.556  25288-25288/com.lameencoder D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_hawaii.so
     03-08 22:57:10.556  25288-25288/com.lameencoder D/﹕ mem_init ++
     03-08 22:57:10.556  25288-25288/com.lameencoder D/﹕ gHwMemAllocator client 3
     03-08 22:57:10.556  25288-25288/com.lameencoder D/﹕ **** Using ION allocator ****
     03-08 22:57:10.556  25288-25288/com.lameencoder D/﹕ registered SIGUSR1[10] for pid[25288]
     03-08 22:57:10.556  25288-25288/com.lameencoder D/﹕ HwMemAllocatorImpl Static Counters 0 0
     03-08 22:57:10.556  25288-25288/com.lameencoder D/﹕ HwMemAllocatorImpl[50059dcc] totalDeviceAllocSize[0] totalFree[0] maxFree[0] in numSlabs[0]
     03-08 22:57:10.566  25288-25288/com.lameencoder D/﹕ mem_init 50059dcc--
     03-08 22:57:10.566  25288-25288/com.lameencoder D/ION﹕ config: version(0x10000) secure(0xf000) 256M(0x22d) fast(0x608) hwwr(0x608)
     03-08 22:57:10.566  25288-25288/com.lameencoder D/MM_DEVICE﹕ Waiting for mm thread to come up
     03-08 22:57:10.566  25288-25303/com.lameencoder D/MM_DEVICE﹕ mm_device_thread starting
     03-08 22:57:10.566  25288-25288/com.lameencoder D/HAWAII_EGL﹕ eglCreateContext() config: 18 context: 0x50092d10, VC context 1, Thread 25288
     03-08 22:57:10.566  25288-25288/com.lameencoder D/HAWAII_EGL﹕ Set SWAP INTERVAL 0
     03-08 22:57:10.566  25288-25288/com.lameencoder D/HAWAII_EGL﹕ eglCreateWindowSurface() surface: 0x40046ad0, VC surface: 1, Thread: 25288
     03-08 22:57:10.566  25288-25288/com.lameencoder D/HAWAII_EGL﹕ eglMakeCurrent(0x50092d10, 0x40046ad0, 0x40046ad0) Thread: 25288
     03-08 22:57:10.566  25288-25288/com.lameencoder D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
     03-08 22:57:11.667  25288-25310/com.lameencoder W/System.err﹕ java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/20150308225711.raw: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
     03-08 22:57:11.667  25288-25310/com.lameencoder W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:416)
     03-08 22:57:11.667  25288-25310/com.lameencoder W/System.err﹕ at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
     03-08 22:57:11.667  25288-25310/com.lameencoder W/System.err﹕ at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:73)
     03-08 22:57:11.667  25288-25310/com.lameencoder W/System.err﹕ at com.lameencoder.MainActivity$3.run(MainActivity.java:127)
     03-08 22:57:11.667  25288-25310/com.lameencoder W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
     03-08 22:57:11.667  25288-25310/com.lameencoder W/System.err﹕ Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
     03-08 22:57:11.667  25288-25310/com.lameencoder W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
     03-08 22:57:11.667  25288-25310/com.lameencoder W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
     03-08 22:57:11.667  25288-25310/com.lameencoder W/System.err﹕ at  libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:400)
     03-08 22:57:11.677  25288-25310/com.lameencoder W/System.err﹕ ... 4 more
     03-08 22:57:12.908  25288-25288/com.lameencoder D/LAME ENCODER﹕ Encoding started
     03-08 22:57:12.908  25288-25288/com.lameencoder A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000004 (code=1), thread 25288 (com.lameencoder)
```

`

thanks in advance...

nice meeting you all..

Comment: Ummm... so it could not open the file?  Why have you commented out the path-getting thing?  What did you find out about the file spec when running under the debugger?

Comment: thanks for your reply.. I thought the line had some error in it so I surrounded it with a try catch block but in the end surrounding it with the try catch block caused a error.... so i did comment it...                                                          but the problem I see in the code is when I try to encode the file that happens after the stopRecord's button..

Comment: i have same issue when press stop button - and no answer - when you find something write some info

Comment: For now my solution is call Lame.closeEncoder(); delayed (250ms) after stop

Comment: I don't know what is  the problem in my code but i just used another sample project in github which worked perfect for me...if interested visit this link.....                                                                                                this had a different structure of lame library file i just made changes for my project and it worked perfect https://github.com/yhirano/Mp3VoiceRecorderSampleForAndroid